# Could not find i18n-1.1.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger, rails-i18n

I recently updated to Ruby 2.5.3 and Rails 5.2.1. Here si the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 3.0'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.6'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', '~> 1.6'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1'
gem 'd3-rails'
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.14'
gem 'nested_form_fields'
gem 'pg'

# XLSX format support
gem 'iconv'
gem 'write_xlsx'
gem 'roo'

# Authorisations
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 2.0'

# MarkDown parser
gem 'redcarpet'
# eMail notification support
gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.1'

# gem for dev and test only
group :development, :test, :eval do
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.7'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '4.0.0.rc1'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.7'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.53'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '~>3.1'
  gem 'listen',                '~>3.0'
  gem 'spring',                '~>1.7'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0'
end
```

As far as I know, i18n is included in Rails 5, but 1.1.1 version seems to be missing. I run the bundler update, tried to remove Gemfile.lock, install gem i18n directly:

```
/var/www/dqm$ gem install gem install i18n                
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'gem' (>= 0) in any repository                 
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: gem                                         
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'install' (>= 0) in any repository  
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: installr, go-install, insta, instacli, instana 
Successfully installed i18n-1.1.1
```

but still the issue is raised with Passenger.

*(Starting the application on WEBrick works with no issue.)*

But Passenger returns following error:

> Could not find i18n-1.1.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

with the following trace:

```
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize'
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:171:in `specs'
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:238:in `specs_for'
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:227:in `requested_specs'
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:363:in `activate_gem'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:527:in `running_bundler'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:91:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

How can I solve this ? Any idea is welcome... Thanks!

Comment: I have a stoopid question, have you restarted the server?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried to upgrade Passenger and then restart. The result is the same, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in my service configuration file, I also need to set the consistent version for Ruby: 2.5.3. My virtual host declaration should contain the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dqm.---.com
    RailsEnv development
    # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dqm/public

    PassengerRuby /home/fred/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/ruby
---
```

This solved my issue!